# What does `?` mean in this Perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a Perl regex. But I'm not sure what "?" means in this context.

```
m#(?:\w+)#
```

What does `?` mean here?

Comment: Beginning with the most obvious: perlre (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Comment: @msw and one of them is [this page right here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890739/what-does-mean-in-this-perl-regex?rq=1).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In this case, the `?` is actually being used in connection with the `:`. Put together, `?:` at the beginning of a grouping means to group but not capture the text/pattern within the parentheses (as in, it will not be stored in any backreferences like `\1` or `$1`, so you will not be able to access the grouped text directly).

More specifically, a `?` has three distinct meanings in regex:

1. The `?` quantifier signifies "zero or one repetitions" of an expression. One of the canonical examples I've seen is `s?he` which will match both `she` and `he` since the `?` makes the `s` "optional"
2. When a quantifier (`+`, `*`, `?`, or the general `{n,m}`) is followed by a `?` then the match is non-greedy (i.e. it will match the shortest string starting from that position that allows the match to proceed)
3. A `?` at the beginning of a parenthesized group signifies that you want to perform a special action. As in this case, `:` means to group but not capture. The exact list of actions available will vary somewhat from one regex engine to another, but here's a list (not necessarily all-inclusive) of some of them:

   A. [Non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html): `(?:text)`
    B. [Lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): `(?=a)` for a lookahead, `?!` for negative lookahead, or `?<=` and `?<!` for lookbehinds (positive and negative, respectively).
    C. [Conditional Matches](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html): `(?(condition)then|else)`.
    D. [Atomic Grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html): `a(?>bc|b)c` (matches `abcc` but *not* `abc`; see the link)
    E. [Inline enabling/disabling of regex matching modifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html): `?i` to enable a mode, `?-i` to disable. You can also enable/disable more than one modifier at a time by simply concatenating them, such as `?im` (`i` is case insensitive and `m` is multiline).
    F. [Named capture groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html): `(?P<name>pattern)`, which can later be referenced using `(?P=name)`. The .NET regex engine uses the syntax `(?<name>pattern)` instead.
    G. [Comments](http://www.regular-expressions.info/comments.html): `(?#Comment text)`. I personally think this just adds clutter, but I guess it could serve some use...[free-spacing mode](http://www.regular-expressions.info/freespacing.html) might be a better option (the `(?x)` modifier).

So essentially, the purpose of the `?` is just contextual. If you wanted zero or more repetitions of a literal `(` character you'd have to use `\(?` to escape the paren.

Comment: For point #3, there's also `(?>...)`, which is an [atomic group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) in flavours that support it, and `(?i)` and `(?-i)` for inline enabling/disabling of [modifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html).

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks. I think I'm going to clean up #3 and add a list with some links, so that then other people can continue to add to it as well.

Comment: Just for clarity, `(?im)` enables two modes (case insensitive and multiline) ;)

Comment: @Daniel Vandersluis: Right, edited to make that clearer in the answer. I could see how that was not evident in my original phrasing. I think this is a bit better :)

Answer (score 7):

[$ perldoc perlreref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html):

> `(?:...)`           Groups subexpressions without capturing (cluster)

You [can also use](http://blog.nu42.com/2010/09/explain-this-regex-to-me.html) [YAPE::Regex::Explain](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/YAPE::Regex::Explain):

```
C:\\Temp> perl -MYAPE::Regex::Explain -e \ 
"print YAPE::Regex::Explain->new(qr#(?:\w+)#)->explain"

The regular expression:

(?-imsx:(?:\w+))

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

Those are non-capturing parentheses. They're used for grouping (just like normal parentheses) but the group won't be added to the capture array (i.e. it won't be referenceable with \n).

See here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html

Answer (score 2):

In short, the sequence `(?` starts a regular expression special feature. The things that follow the `(?` specify the special feature, in this case, a non-capturing grouping. We cover this in both *Intermediate Perl* and *Effective Perl Programming*. The [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) documents Perl regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

See the [regex tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) that is installed with every version of Perl (in particular, [this section](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Non-capturing-groupings)).