# regex-match everything to str1 or str2

Tags: regex, string, string-matching

The input string has 2 scenarios mixed up. Example below.

**Scenario 1:**

/*start*/ sky is blue today; /*transition*/ it is raining; /*end*/

**Scenario 2:**

/*start*/ sky is blue today; /*end*/

In the input string, there are both scenarios 1 and 2. What I want to grab is:

1. if  /*transition*/ exist, then grab /*start*/ sky is blue today;
2. if /*transition*/ does not exist, then grab /*start*/ sky is blue today; /*end*/.

Can you please help me with the regex expression?

Comment: If you're looking for [`^.*?(?=\/transition\/|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/nXZvMx/1) it's most likely a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

This works too:

```bash
(((\|start\|[^\;]*\; (?=\|transition\|[^\;]*\; \|end\|.*)))|((\|start\|[^\;]*\; \|end\|.*)))
```

### Discussion

I think the generic form of your question is this:

1. If there exists a string "${start}${transition}${end}"
2. Where "start","transition", and "end" are variable strings with the format "tag content semicolon space"
3. How does one conditionally grab parts of the string
4. The conditions being:
   a) if transition tag exists return "$start"
   b) else return "${start}${end}"

Logic in regex can be accomplished by explicitly stating all acceptable scenarios, here's some bash to play around with our regex:

```bash
tst1="|start| example1; |transition| example2; |end| example3"
tst2="|start| example1; |end| example3"
tst3="|start| sky is blue today; |transition| it is raining; |end|"
tst4="|start| sky is blue today; it is raining; |end|"
tst5="|start| sky is blue today; |end|"

start='|start|[^\;]*\; '           # start marker, 0+ of any character but a semicolon, then a semicolon, then a space
start="${start//\|/\\|}"           # escape |'s
transition='|transition|[^\;]*\; ' # transition marker, 0+ of any character but a semicolon, then a semicolon, then a space
transition="${transition//\|/\\|}" # escape |'s
end='|end|.*'                      # end marker, 0+ of any character
end="${end//\|/\\|}"               # escape |'s

start_when_transition="(${start}(?=${transition}${end}))" # match start if transition and end
end_when_transition="(${start}${transition}\K${end})"     # match end if begining and transition
start_and_end="(${start}${end})"                          # match start and end when no transition in the middle
ifTransition="(${start_when_transition})"                            
else="(${start_and_end})"

echo tst1: $tst1
echo $tst1 | grep -oP "(${ifTransition}|${else})" | xargs echo -e "\t"
echo -----------------------------------------------------------------
echo tst2: $tst2
echo $tst2 | grep -oP "(${ifTransition}|${else})" | xargs echo -e "\t"
echo -----------------------------------------------------------------
echo tst3: $tst3
echo $tst3 | grep -oP "(${ifTransition}|${else})" | xargs echo -e "\t"
echo -----------------------------------------------------------------
echo tst4: $tst4 
echo $tst4 | grep -oP "(${ifTransition}|${else})" | xargs echo -e "\t"
echo -----------------------------------------------------------------
echo tst5: $tst5 
echo $tst5 | grep -oP "(${ifTransition}|${else})" | xargs echo -e "\t"
```

output:

```
tst1: |start| example1; |transition| example2; |end| example3
     |start| example1;
-----------------------------------------------------------------
tst2: |start| example1; |end| example3
     |start| example1; |end| example3
-----------------------------------------------------------------
tst3: |start| sky is blue today; |transition| it is raining; |end|
     |start| sky is blue today;
-----------------------------------------------------------------
tst4: |start| sky is blue today; it is raining; |end|
    
-----------------------------------------------------------------
tst5: |start| sky is blue today; |end|
     |start| sky is blue today; |end|
```

#### Bash reviewed

- [echo](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/echo.1.html) is a string printing program
- echo -e allows for extended string stuff like "\t" for tab
- [grep](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) is a string matching program
- grep -oP -> -o is for --only-matching and -P is for Perl, an extended regex launguage
- | aka "pipe", takes the output from the last command and feeds it into the next
- [xargs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) is a program takes its input and adds it as arguments to the following command
- $variablename access variable we set
- "${variablename}" access variable we set within a string

#### Regex reviewed

- \K if you made it this far, great, but forget everything you just matched
- ?= look ahead to see if somethings there but don't match
- () scope conditions
- | or
- []  match any characters listed- character class
- [^] match any characters but the ones listed
- \ escape special character

#### Regex combinations reviewed

- [abc]* - match a, b, or c 0+ times
- foo(?=bar) match foo if bar comes right after

#### References

- [What does ? mean in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890739/what-does-mean-in-this-perl-regex)
- [\K regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33573920/what-does-k-mean-in-this-regex)